# MethodInfo of Func<T1, TResult>?

Tags: .net-core, reflection

I have a `Delegate` that points to `Func<T1, TResult>` compiled from `LambdaExpression`.

When I'm using `delegate.GetMethodInfo().GetParameters()` I see 2 parameters instead of 1!

So in debugger watch `MethodInfo` looks like:

```
{TResult lambda_method(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, System.String)}
```

Why there is 2 parameters? How to get `MethodInfo` with correct number of parameters?

Minimal reproduce code:

```cs
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "x");
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(param, param);
var delegate = lambda.Compile();

Debug.Assert(delegate.GetMethodInfo().GetParameters().Length == 1, "params count should be 1");
```

Comment: I poked around and it looks like `Closure` parameter is something like `this` value captured by `Delegate.Target` but supplied inside through first parameter. But somehow this parameter is only present when `Func` is compiled from `LambdaExpression`.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that reproduces this observation?

Comment: I have added minimal example to question code.